How do i set up MacOS Screen Sharing only through SSH?
I am physically in another country, and I want to set up Screen Sharing on my MacBook Pro running 10.15. The problem is that I didn't even think of setting up Screen Sharing before I travelled, meaning that most settings related to screen sharing would be in their default state (especially since it would be impossible for me to interact with any GUI elements until I successfully set up screen sharing). In addition, I recently rebooted the system and logged myself out.
So far, I already have a VPN connection to my home network, enabled remote AppleScript execution, have sudo, and set up ssh. What do I do to get any sort of Screen Sharing (Apple Remote Desktop, VNC, X11 Forwarding, ?) to work?

I forgot to mention, but I did set up wakeonlan for the mac and enable wake for network access.
